# What is the difference between these two defines

Tags: c, c99

In the following, what is the difference between MY_INT2 and MY_INT3 declarations?
I have a fairly entrenched issue in some code so reducing the code that generates bugs into a test case would be rather challenging.

```
#define MY_INT1 5
#define MY_INT2 31
#define MY_INT3 (int) pow(2, MY_INT1)-1
```

I'm getting issues in my code which are resolved by using the following, which feels very unnecessary

```
int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a*b;
}

int someFunction(int in) {
     //nice
     return floor(in/MY_INT2);
}

int someFunction2(int in) {
     //silly
     return floor(in/mul(1,MY_INT3));
}

int someFunction3(int in) {
     //cast does not solve the issue
     return floor(in/(int)MY_INT3);
}
```

Comment: What is the error? You didnt say what is actually occurring ...

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of macros, where extra parentheses are almost mandatory.

Comment: Also, you do know that `pow` is a *floating point* function? If you want a power of 2 as an integer, use *bit shifting* (like e.g. `1 << 5`).

Comment: Do not use `pow` for this. Some math library implementations will return a result with some error even for integer inputs. So `pow(2, 5)` may return a value slightly under 32, and converting it to `int` will produce 31. To compute powers of two, use bit-shifts, such as `1 << x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are text replacements. Without parentheses `in / (int) MY_INT3` is in fact

```
in / (int) (int) pow(2, 5) - 1;
```

which is the same as

```
in / 32 - 1;
```

so the `-1` is subtracted after the division.

Also, `mul(1, MY_INT3)` works because the parameter is evaluated when passed to the function, in fact

```
in / (MY_INT3);
```

should also "*work*" as you would expect.

It appears that you think that casting is some magic issue solving trick, and it's not. Casting just tells the compiler how to represent the value, nothing else.

Comment: The right solution is to put the parentheses in the macro itself.